# Cannot load localStorage key into a <h> tag

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make an small game as practice but I'm having a problem loading the name key from localStorage and putting it in tag.

```html
<div id="profilescr" class="thetab">
    <h3 id="tpname"></h3>
</div>
```

```js
if(localStorage.user === undefined) {
    localStorage.user = prompt("Name plz");
    document.getElementById("tpname").innerHTML = localStorage.user;
}
```

I stored `.user` successfully but it is failing to show up in `<h3>` tag.

Comment: Duplicate of [*Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element) (based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54043920/cannot-load-localstorage-key-into-a-h-tag/54043951?noredirect=1#comment94923935_54043951)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're only updating the `h3` when the value isn't stored. If the value *is* stored, you're not updating it, because you've put the update **inside** the `if`. Move it outside it:

```
if(localStorage.user === undefined) {
    localStorage.user = prompt("Name plz");
}
document.getElementById("tpname").innerHTML = localStorage.user; // <====
```

[Live Example on plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/RoE3U7uq3BCkYtrxdF7i?p=preview) (since Stack Snippets don't allow local storage)

Comment: I already did that many times, but the `.user` name isn't showing in the `h3` tag.

Comment: @Teki - Your question doesn't mention trying this, which is why I posted the answer. It **does** work, provided `localStorage` isn't blocked on the device/site you're doing this on. (For instance: `localStorage` is blocked on jsFiddle.) Look in your web console to see if storage is blocked.

Comment: It still doesn't work on my full code. `.user` name has to be loaded into `h3` tag in an Tab so maybe that is problem? I didn't posted my full code.

Comment: @Teki - It doesn't matter where the `h3` is. If it exists in the DOM as of when you call `getElementById` (and it's the **only** element with that ID, which is a requirement of the `id` attribute in HTML), this works. You'll need to debug (really, that's the first step anyway) to figure out where things are going wrong.

Comment: I got an error in console saying: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null, and code 15 is `document.getElementById("tpname").innerHTML = localStorage.user;`

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `localStorage.user`, use the methods `localStorage.setItem()` and `localStorage.getItem()`.

I'd change your code to the following:

```
if(localStorage.getItem("gameInfo") === null){
    askForName();
}else{
    const userName = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("gameInfo")).userName;
    document.getElementById("tpname").innerHTML = userName;
}
```

And for the askForName function:

```
function askForName(){
    const name = *some input value*;
    localStorage.setItem("gameInfo", JSON.stringify({userName: name}))
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, it just suggests doing something different that should *also* work. Using named properties is [absolutely supported](https://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#the-storage-interface). From the link: *"The supported property names on a Storage object are the keys of each key/value pair currently present in the list associated with the object."*